# How add my root Scroll View inertia effect or change this code for my case

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, drawer

Again, I appeal to your wisdom, because I can not solve my problem. I have a drawer with two listView. I need general scroll for all view,and i can make this, but without inertia effect. I'm crying because i'm lost three day on this problem. I'm trying make this case through menu in xml and with NavigationDrawer, but this doesn't help. I'm trying put my listview in ONE BIG ROOT LISTVIEW in Drawer, but that is creepy. please, help me. I know, that ScrollView with listView is bad solution, but what can i do? Here my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    </include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_common_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_common_margin"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_common_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_common_margin">

        <TextView
            style="@style/drawerHeading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/label_cabinet_list_view"
            android:text="@string/drawer_personal_cabinet_header" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/cabinet_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_min_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_common_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_common_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_min_margin"
            android:divider="@color/colorAccentLight"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            />

        <TextView
            style="@style/drawerHeading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/drawer_menu_header" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menu_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_min_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_common_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_common_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_min_margin"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:divider="@color/colorAccentLight"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />



    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - I'm found answer for my question. As my drawer doesn't contain much
>        view-elements, I am a refused from ListView and RecycleView, and just
>        posted them in ScrollView.Of course, I do not think, that this is a
>        best solution, but other I not found.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:openDrawer="start">


            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none">

            </include>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:id="@+id/scroll_drawer">

                <include layout="@layout/content_main"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

                </include>

            </ScrollView>


        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```